# Type uint256[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] storage ref

Tags: ethereum, polygon, solidity, remix

I can't get rid of this error in RemixIDE. My client gave me addresses similar to below to push them to a whitelist mapping but I get this error. What is the solution?

error
TypeError: Type uint256[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] storage ref.

```
address[] public users = [0xd22Ab922D5ABE0810798aec78c20FA232C7Ea810798aec78c20FA232C7Ea5fa];
    mapping(address => bool) whitelist;

    constructor () {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            whitelist[users[i]] = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is ```0xd22Ab922D5ABE0810798aec78c20FA232C7Ea810798aec78c20FA232C7Ea5fa``` ? The address must be 40 hex characters long.